# Taking the image from sd card

Tags: android

When I am taking the image from sd card its working fine in my mobile (micromax canvas hd), but its not working in galaxy nexus. In galaxy nexus its showing the null pointer exception.

```
 if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // our BitmapDrawable for the thumbnail
                    BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = null;
                    // try to retrieve the image using the data from the intent
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(),
                            null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null) {

                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                        Log.d("file path","file path name"+selectedImagePath);


                        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.DATA);
                        String fileSrc = cursor.getString(idx);
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc); // load
                                                                            // preview
                                                                            // image
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                                100, 100, false);
                        // bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapPreview);
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        data1 = null;
```

this is log file---

```
    12-30 14:37:26.480: E/CursorWindow(14558): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 6 columns.
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558): Process: com.app.postevery, PID: 14558
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:30713 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.app.postevery/com.app.postevery.PostEvery}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at com.app.postevery.PostEvery.onActivityResult(PostEvery.java:548)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
12-30 14:37:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(14558):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: sory, this time i don't have nexus mobile. but this code is working on my mobile.

Comment: I have found this same situation in my galaxy nexus. put     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to your manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following code to get Image from sdcard. This code is working properly in Nexus 5.

```
   Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);  
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

**onActivityResult()** method

```
     protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Main Activity", "On Activity Result");



    try {
        Uri selectedImage=null;
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Log.d("Main Activity", "Gallery");
            selectedImage = data.getData();
        }

        if(selectedImage==null)
        {
            Log.d("Main Activity","Back");
            return;
        }

        Log.d("Main Activity","Out");
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Log.d("Main Activity",picturePath);
        cursor.close();
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Main Activity","Exception");

    }      


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked it with Nexus device.
Start your chooser intent like

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), GALLERY_PICTURE);
```

And else code in onActivityResult are same.
you don't need to check for sdcard for nexus device as Nexus device has internel storage with emulated Sdcard path.

Another thing was some of the files in sdcard are as URI only. which must be download first for getting it from sdcard. You can refere [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2013/03/easy-image-chooser-library-for-android.html) and [this](https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library)

Answer (score 0):

This is something obvious as Nexus series is not supported to external storage options.

So, At first check for the device if it has SD card.

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // yes SD-card is present

//    Fetch from SD card i.e. Path for SD card

// path = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/Folder Name";
}
else
{
 // path = getFilesDir() + "/Folder Name";
}
```